# How can I return last intent without losing texts inside the textfields

Tags: android, android-intent

In my program, there is some textfields and a button which is opens a camera intent. (assume that the page's name is mainIntent)... Lets assume that, user fills textfields and clicked the button; cameraIntent opens, user shots the photo.. Now, I want program to return the page which have textfields and button. But if I do

```
Intent i = new Intent(cameraIntent.this, mainIntent.class);
startActivity(i);
```

All the texts which are written by user are gone. I need to use something like `return mainIntent` I suppose...

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you calling `finish();` when camera intent is called?

Comment: no, I didn't use finish();

Comment: Try to use `startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode);` in place of Starting a new activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29) in first activity. So you will be able to return to calling activity. And you won't lose data of edit texts.

```
Intent i = new Intent(mainIntent.this, cameraIntent.class);
startActivityForResult(i, MY_REQ_CODE);
```

You can add this for `onActivityResult()`:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
      {
      switch(requestCode) {
      case MY_REQ_CODE: 
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                //Do action that's needed
                break;
            }

      }
}
```

In your activity next activity, you will just need to call `setResult()` and `finish()` as follows. You won't need to start new activity here:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("ImageName",imgName);   //Required if you want to pass some data back
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);        
finish();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @ArdaOğulÜçpınar, That code should be written in second activity when you intend to return back to previous activity after capturing image.

Comment: I don no y do you need to start an activity for result there, saving current instance should work well to restore back

Answer (score 3):

You need to override onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) and write the application state values you want to change to the Bundle parameter like this:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Save UI state changes to the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle will be passed to onCreate if the process is
  // killed and restarted.
  savedInstanceState.putBoolean("MyBoolean", true);
  savedInstanceState.putDouble("myDouble", 1.9);
  savedInstanceState.putInt("MyInt", 1);
  savedInstanceState.putString("MyString", "Welcome back to Android");
  // etc.
}
```

The Bundle is essentially a way of storing a NVP ("Name-Value Pair") map, and it will get passed in to onCreate and also onRestoreInstanceState where you'd extract the values like this:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  // Restore UI state from the savedInstanceState.
  // This bundle has also been passed to onCreate.
  boolean myBoolean = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("MyBoolean");
  double myDouble = savedInstanceState.getDouble("myDouble");
  int myInt = savedInstanceState.getInt("MyInt");
  String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("MyString");
}
```

You'd usually use this technique to store instance values for your application (selections, unsaved text, etc.).